# JavaScript sort date followed by time in descending order

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, time

I was having some problem to sort the date followed by time in descending order using JavaScript. Here is some inputs:

```
[{chatroomID: "1", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:31:32 PM"},
{chatroomID: "2", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:38:01 PM"},
{chatroomID: "3", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:35:14 PM"}]
```

I wanted to sort them in descending order whereby the latest one will be on top but I not sure how to do it.

The desired output:

```
[{chatroomID: "2", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:38:01 PM"},
{chatroomID: "3", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:35:14 PM"},
{chatroomID: "1", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:31:32 PM"}]
```

If the result comes from the same date, then I will sort according to time. Otherwise, the latest date will be on top. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: First you should convert the dates and times to date objects then you should have a look at [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just concat the `date` and `time`, then parse it to a `Date` and get the timestamp. From then on, it's just plain old sorting.

```js
const datetimes = [
  {chatroomID: "1", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:31:32 PM"},
  {chatroomID: "2", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:38:01 PM"},
  {chatroomID: "3", date: "12/26/2017", time: "10:35:14 PM"}
]

const sorted = datetimes.sort((a, b) => {
  const aDate = new Date(a.date + ' ' + a.time)
  const bDate = new Date(b.date + ' ' + b.time)
  
  return bDate.getTime() - aDate.getTime()
})

console.log(sorted)
```

**Update**: The linked answer in the comment by Marcel Gwerder indicates you could just skip `getTime()` altogether and just compare the Dates.

Comment: I think using `new Date` or `Date.parse` with a string sill isn't a really safe thing to do, see [the note on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Fair point - I doubt browsers will be inconsistent with the OP's formats   - but I wouldn't swear on this.